Calculating the integral $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\cos^2(3\theta)}{5-4\sin(2\theta)}d\theta$ using residue theorem
I'm trying to solve this integral:
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\cos^2(3\theta)}{5-4\sin(2\theta)}d\theta
$$
[UPDATE: Note this is not the same integral as the one solved here even though very similar].
using conversion to a contour integral over the unit circle $U$ and then using the residue theorem for any singularities inside the unit circle.
In my attempt at such conversion (for $z = e^{i\theta}, dz=(iz)d\theta$) I end up with a fairly hairy rational function to work with:
$$
\int_{U} \frac{z^{12}+2z^{6}+1}{4z^5(-2z^4 + 10iz^2 + 2)}dz
$$
I suppose in theory I could try to find zeros of the denominator (0 is obviously one) and use various residue finding lemmas, but this exercise is not supposed to be about too much algebraic manipulations.
So I'm assuming I either got something wrong in calculation or there's some major simplification possible?

No mistakes here. You can easily factorize the quartic in the denominator and decide which poles fall within $U$. Getting the residue $\star$ at $0$ will take some work, and perhaps best done by partial fraction expansion,$$\frac{\star}z + \frac{\cdot}{z^2} + \cdots + \frac{\cdot}{z^5}+\frac{\cdot}{\rm quartic}$$

First substitute $w = z^2$, $dw = 2 z \,dz$ to transform the integral to
$$-\oint_{2 U} \frac{(w^3 + 1)^2 \,dw}{16 w^3 (w - 2 i) \left(w - \frac{i}2\right)} .$$
As $z$ traverses $U$ once, $w$ traverses $U$ twice---we denote this doubled contour by $2 U$. So, if we denote the integrand by $f(w)$, the desired integral is
$$-2 \oint_U f(w) \,dw .$$ The poles of $f$ are at $0, \frac{i}2, 2 i$, and only the first two are inside $U$, so the Residue Theorem gives
$$\oint_U f(w) \,dw = 2 \pi i \left(\operatorname{Res}(f; 0) + \operatorname{Res}\left(f; \frac{i}2\right)\right) .$$
If we expand $f$ in a Laurent series about $0$, only the $1$ term in the expanded numerator can contribute to the $w^k$ terms with $k < 0$, quickly giving the expansion
$$f(w) \sim \frac{1}{16} \left(-w^{-3} + \frac{5 i}{2} w^{-2} + \frac{21}{4} w^{-1} + \cdots\right),$$
so $$\operatorname{Res}(f; 0) = \frac{21}{64}$$
It remains to compute the residue $\operatorname{Res}\left(f; \frac{i}2\right)$ of the simple pole at $\frac{i}2$.

I get $\frac\pi3$ for the value of the original integral.


Thank you sir! Working my way through your solution, I think the 5iw should be a 10iw? Is that right?

I'm reasonably sure it's correct---I think the error is in your original calculation.

Saw my error, missed you calling it out in beginning of your answer - thanks again

I only added that remark after you asked about it!

aha that makes sense :) another one to run by you - I believe the residue of f at zero is actually 21/64 - I got this via the fact that according to my calculations Residue(f, -i/2) = 0 and Residue(f, i/2) = i/12 - 21/64 . Mathematica seems to also confirm the fact that Residue[f[w], {w, 0}] = 21/64 for $f(w) = ((2 w^2 + 5 I*w - 2) (w^3 + 1)^2)/(8 w^3 (w^2 + 4) (4 w^2 +
1))$ which makes sense since when summing these residues and then multiplying by $-2 *  2\pi i$ we get the desired result of $\pi/3$

Ah, you're right this time. In particular the residue at $-\frac{i}2$ is $0$ because the singularity there is removable---making the computation is easier than I thought. I've rewritten my answer to reflect this simplification.
